# Not able to click on xpath which is exist

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I have an element that I'm not able to locate in protractor. I am using protractor + Jasmine + POM. From the developer console, I am able to locate and its count is 1.

I have added a try and catch block for locating element and it always goes to catch block

```
//let erasertype = element(by.xpath("//a[@data-tool='Eraser']"));
let erasertype = element(By.xpath("//a[@data-tooloption='eraser']"));
this.selecterasertype = async () => {
    try {
        await erasertype.click();
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log("Not able to select erasertype ");
    }
```

Comment: You have caught the error but why to console it to see the actual error.

Answer (score 0):

```
element(By.xpath('//a[@data-tooloption="raser"]'))
```

Interchange the ' and ".

In order to create a perfect string use template literal ``.

For confirmation catch the error object and print it